# Show instructions based on the answers to a previous selection

Tags: show-hide

I need to create a very simple web based tool for providing open source license related instructions to users based on the questions they have answered. I want one question to be visible at a time and the next question or instruction would be displayed based on the answer to the previous question.

This should be very simple to implement but with zero programming skills I'm unable to do this on my own. Would someone be able to guide me to right direction with this? Here are the specs:

1 Select license
a) Apache
b) MIT
c) BSD
d) LGPL v2
e) LGPL v3
f) GPL v2
g) GPL v3

- if A, B or C > show instruction X
- if D, E, F, G > show question 2

2 Is the GPL/LGPL component distributed?
a) yes
b) no

- if A > show question 3
- if B > show instruction Y

3 Commercial/proprietary license available? 
a) yes
b) no
c) yes, but not affordable

- if A > show instruction Z
- if B > show question 4 if 1D/1E or show instruction Q if 1F/1G
- if C > show question 4 if 1D/1E or show instruction Q if 1F/1G

4 Is the LGPL component combined with Company's proprietary software?
a) yes
b) no

- if A > show instruction R
- if B > show instruction E